# Old records change (undesirably) after adding new Many-to-Many object

Tags: sqlite-net-extensions

When I add new Many-to-Many object, some relationship fields value in old records are set to null or 0 (Reference: Image 1).

[image: Quotes Table]

Also some previous intermediate tables record are deleted (Reference: Image 2).

[image: QuoterProfession intermediate table]

Here is the code:

Models:

```
public class ModelBase 
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]        
    public int Id {set; get;}
}


[Table(nameof(Quoter))]
public class Quoter : ModelBase
{
    [Unique, MaxLength(30)]
        public string Name {set; get;}

        [ManyToMany(typeof(QuoterProfession), CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeInsert | CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
        public List<Profession> Professions {set; get;}

        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
        public List<Quote> Quotes {set; get;}
}


[Table(nameof(Quote))]
public class Quote : ModelBase
{
        public string Statement {set; get;}

        [ForeignKey(typeof(Quoter))]
        public int QuoterId { get; set; }
        [ManyToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeInsert | CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
        public Quoter Quoter {set; get;}

        [ForeignKey(typeof(Profession))]
        public int ProfessionId { get; set; }
        [ManyToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeInsert | CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
        public Profession Profession {set; get;}
}


[Table(nameof(Profession))]
public class Profession : ModelBase
{
        [Unique, MaxLength(20)]
        public string Name {set; get;}

        [ManyToMany(typeof(QuoterProfession), CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeInsert | CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
        public List<Quoter> Quoters {set; get;}

        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeInsert | CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
        public List<Quote> Quotes {set; get;}
}


[Table(nameof(QuoterProfession))]
class QuoterProfession : ModelBase
{
        [ForeignKey(typeof(Quoter))]
        public int QuoterId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(typeof(Profession))]
        public int ProfessionId { get; set; }
 }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class AddQuoterPageVm   
{
    public Quoter Quoter { get; set; }

        public List<Profession> Professions { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Profession> QuoterProfessions { get; set; }
        public Profession QuoterProfession { get; set; }

        public Profession QuoteProfession { get; set; }

        public Quote Quote { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }

    public void SaveQuoter()   // Add a new Quoter with all his properties & Save
    {
        Quoter = new Quoter {Name = "QuoterN"};
        asyncConnection.InsertWithChildrenAsync(Quoter).Wait();   // Adds a new Quoter to database


        AddProfessions();   // Add profession to database
        Professions = asyncConnection.GetAllWithChildrenAsync<Profession>().Result;

        // Add QuoterN's profession
    QuoterProfessions = new ObservableCollection<Profession>{ Professions[0], Professions[1] };
        Quoter.Professions = new List<Profession>(QuoterProfessions);

        Quotes = new ObservableCollection<Quote> 
        {
            new Quote {Statement = "q1 q1", Profession = Professions[0]},
            new Quote {Statement = "q1 q2", Profession = Professions[1]}
        };
    Quoter.Quotes = new List<Quote>(Quotes);   // Add QuoterN's quotes
            Quotes = null;  

    // Update QuoterN in database after adding additional properties
        asyncConnection.InsertOrReplaceWithChildrenAsync(Quoter, true);   
    }

    private void AddProfessions()   // Adds professions to database
    {
        asyncConnection.GetAllWithChildrenAsync()
                    .ContinueWith(professionListTask =>
                {
                    if (professionListTask.Result.Any()) return;

                    var professions = new List<Profession>
                    {
                        new Profession {Name = "Profession1"},
                        new Profession {Name = "Profession2"},
                        new Profession {Name = "Profession3"},
                        new Profession {Name = "Profession4"},
                        new Profession {Name = "Profession5"},
                        new Profession {Name = "Profession6"},
                        new Profession {Name = "Profession7"}
                    };

                    asyncConnection.InsertAllWithChildrenAsync(professions);
                });
    }
}
```

How can I add Quoter without affecting (undesirably) previous records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated Quoter using `asyncConnection.UpdateWithChildren(Quoter)`. After using this old records are not deleted.

Previously I was using `asyncConnection.InsertOrReplaceWithChildrenAsync(Quoter, true)`.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832214/method-sqliteconnection-insertall-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Probably having all relationships recursive at both ends is causing issues because you're only setting one of them and the other end may be inconsistent. As you're not using recursive insert operations I'd recommend you to remove `CascadeOperation.CascadeInsert` from all relationships, or mark the inverse relationships as `ReadOnly`.

I'm not sure if waiting asynchronous operations like that may be causing issues, so I'd try to fix it too. Try awaiting asynchronous operations and returning `Task` instead of `void` to return the resulting task:

```
public async Task SaveQuoter() {

    Quoter = new Quoter {Name = "QuoterN"};
    await asyncConnection.InsertWithChildrenAsync(Quoter);
    await AddProfessions();
    Professions = await asyncConnection.GetAllWithChildrenAsync<Profession>();
    ...
}
```

You can check at the sample code in the [`IntegrationTests` project](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/HEAD/Tests/IntegrationTests/Tests/?at=master) contained in the sources.